# Should I be worried about "md5sums differ" message during apparmor upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, apparmor, md5sum

When I upgraded apparmor yesterday this was the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor gnome-weather htop libapparmor-perl libapparmor1
5 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 5,798 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2 [31.8 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 gnome-weather all 3.20.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [5,213 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor-perl amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2 [31.6 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apparmor amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2 [446 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 htop amd64 2.0.1-1ubuntu1 [76.4 kB]
Fetched 5,798 kB in 7s (773 kB/s)                                                                                                                    
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 247956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapparmor1_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) over (2.10.95-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
(Reading database ... 247956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapparmor-perl_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor-perl (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) over (2.10.95-0ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../apparmor_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apparmor (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) over (2.10.95-0ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-weather_3.20.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-weather (3.20.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (3.20.1-1~xenial1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../htop_2.0.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking htop (2.0.1-1ubuntu1) over (2.0.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libapparmor-perl (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up apparmor (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-session-strict ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Files /var/lib/dpkg/info/apparmor.md5sums and /var/lib/apparmor/profiles/.apparmor.md5sums differ
Setting up gnome-weather (3.20.2-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up htop (2.0.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

The message I am specifically worried about is:

```
Files /var/lib/dpkg/info/apparmor.md5sums and /var/lib/apparmor/profiles/.apparmor.md5sums differ
```

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, I saw the same message in my 16.10 VM as well the previous day. Should I be worried? Do I need to report this? What does it mean?

Comment: I too am seeing this using Ubuntu Server 16.04.1. It's been reported in launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1614215

Comment: The bizarre thing is that when I check these two files afterwards, they do not differ they are identical (except for timestamp).

Comment: @scoobydoo: Strange, same here.